# saveWorkbook function saves without macros

Tags: r, excel, vba

I am trying to use a VBA macro to call an R script to clean data based on variables in the excel workbook. I am having troubles pasting the cleaned data back into the excel workbook.  I can use saveWorkbook to save it as an .xlsm file, however once I open the file, all my pre-set macros are gone, just disappeared. Is there a way to save the xlsm from R that keeps the macros intact?

As another note, is there a way to write this and have it update so that the file does not need to be closed and reopened? Is there a way to have it run in the same manner as a macro?

```
wb <- loadWorkbook(file.xlsm) 
writeData(wb, sheet = "DataSet", data, startCol = 1, startRow = 2, colNames = FALSE) 
saveWorkbook(wb, file = file.xlsm, overwrite = TRUE)
```

It runs fine, but all the macros are gone. The file size goes from 806KB to 27KB

Comment: Specify a macro-enabled Excel workbook file format? I don't know what the R equivalent would be, but in the Excel type library what you want is [Workbook.SaveAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas) with the `FileFormat` argument set to `xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled` (int value is 52)

Comment: when I save the workbook using the function saveWorkbook, I save it as a .xlsm file, so macro enabled. There's only 3 inputs for this function as per the site: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/openxlsx/versions/4.1.0.1/topics/saveWorkbook and I am using them all already

Comment: No, it saves as a .xlsm file, *so as you specified the file extension should be* - that doesn't mean the actual content serialized in the correct format. It's not impossible that this API does not provide a way to save a macro-enabled workbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative solution would be to run your R script with VBA from another Excel file than the one your R script writes to.

You could then use a shell command that can wait for the script to finish before resuming to the rest of your VBA code (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951837/wait-for-shell-command-to-complete) for an example).

When the R script returns, your code could then do the remaining manipulations to the data exported by your R script. If you absolutely need the VBA code to be in that newly generated file, you could also add the VBA code modules in the file (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40956465/vba-to-copy-module-from-one-excel-workbook-to-another-workbook) for an example) and save it as an xlsm file.