# EXCEL VBA - Auto insert code macro, this even possible?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that takes a daily generated report and makes it all nice and neat. I was wondering if it's possible to have that macro insert a module with code into the report or would I have to copy/paste it manually (as I've been doing)?

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx

Comment: Related threads include [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40956465/vba-to-copy-module-from-one-excel-workbook-to-another-workbook).