# Copy data and a button with macros to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy all the data of the workbook into another workbook,
and one of the worksheets has a button which has a macro within itself.

workbook.worksheets.copy()

code above copy the data successful, but a broken button with it.
When I click the button on the new wb, the message "Sorry we couldn't find..XXXXX. Is it possible it was moved, renamed, or deleted?" popped up.

XXXXX is the path of origin workbook.
And I can't see any module in new workbook.

Is there a method could copy all the contents into the new wb?

Comment: No need to tag spam unrelated tags.

Comment: This post seems to provide the answer... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40956465/vba-to-copy-module-from-one-excel-workbook-to-another-workbook

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to transfer a macro/module from one workbook to another using a vba macro.
The button obviously wont work if the underlying macro is not transferred.
However, transferring a macro can only be [done manually](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/copy-a-macro-module-to-another-workbook-13c0938b-8432-4259-9177-a71f7e626de0).

There is no way to copy or transfer a macro using another macro in VBA.

Comment: I want to transfer a macro/module from one workbook to another using VB.net, but CodeModule.Import is invalid in .net.